# How can I get eclipse and the ecj java genetics system to work together nicely?

Tags: java, eclipse, genetic-algorithm

Note: this post is not about the eclipse compiler for java created by eclipse -- just to make sure there's no confusion.

I'm trying to get the ecj genetics programming system to build on eclipse kepler on windows. ecj can be found here:

http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/

The file structure has a base folder ec. It has import references to it, like this one from tutorials1 (MaxOnes.java) found in the ec.app.tutorials1 folder.

```
package ec.app.tutorial1;
import ec.*;
import ec.simple.*;
import ec.vector.*;
```

I've built a new project called ecj using, *Use project folder as root for source and class files* when creating the project, and added ec as a folder under that to store everything.

The imports give an error of,

```
    the import ec cannot be resolved
```

and that the package does not match.

Eclipse recommends a fix to create a project folder called ec, but there already is one at ecj.ec  :/

Removing ec.

```
package app.tutorial1;
import ec.*;     <--- ???
import simple.*;
import vector.*;
```

fixes the reference issue for imports (as if the project is referenced to ec already) but does not find a java file in the ec.simple folder which should have been imported. I'm sure this is just a simple setup issue that I've just never come across before.

I've also tried created a project called ec with the same issues. The ecj codebase is designed for a unix environment with a normal java hierarchy. On linux I would set the CLASSPATH to resolve these issues, but have never had to deal with this issue in eclipse.

What I want to do is to get the tutorials and other code to compile as written for unix, so no special projects or file location swaps. Apparently Robert Baruch's YouTube videos explained all this, but they're gone from YouTube.

I'm waiting for a reply on the ecj mail list and will update here when I get an answer. This post then can serve as a reference to help others when they can't find an answer to set up ecj genetics on eclipse, in case Baruch's YouTube videos go missing again.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I thought I needed the tutorial1 file MaxOnes.java as the Main class file in the run configuration. Obviously the parameter file must handle this linkage. Thanks to Xiaomeng Ye from ECJ-INTEREST-L for the clue.

For any others needing to know this is how I did it...

1. Create a new project called ecj,

   - select Use project folder as root for sources and class files
   - click Finish
2. Right click on the ecj folder and select Import...

   - click on the File System folder and click Next
   - Browse for the ec folder from the downloaded archive,
     mine was 
     C:\ecj\ec  <-- you want the files from the ec folder
   - click on the check box beside the ec folder to select all the files
   - click on the Create top-level folder check box and click Finish
     open the ecj project and you'll see all subfolders have ec. referencing
3. To set up the run configuration (tutorial1 given)

   - click on Run (main menu) Run Configurations...
   - under Java Application click on the New button
   - type in a Name, 
     tutorial1
   - for the Main class: type 
     ec.Evolve
   - click on the Arguments tab
   - in the Program arguments box type in,
     -file ec/app/tutorial1/tutorial1.params
   - click Apply
4. To try out tutorial1 click on Run

   - you'll get an error message if Eclipse is set up that way
   - look in your console window for output

Hope this helps others out there to get up and running on ecj faster.

Answer (score 0):

Will tell how I'd try to solve the problem.
As I see **ecj.tar.gz** or **ecj.zip** don't contain jar files and inside you have java and class files, so I'd create project called **ecj** (what a imagination) from sources. Creating new project pick a source from outside the workspace and select the folder where you decompressed **ecj.zip**. Keep source and compiled files in the same directory (as they are in ecj).

Well, now go to your other project, the one that needs ecj. Right click on the project's root, Properties - Java Build Path and go to "Projects" tab. Select your ecj project and click OK.

After recompiling the project you must get all the dependencies and imports you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The project I want to run is inside the source. It's a tutorial file. I'm trying to get a set up that will work for the tutorials without any other mods.

By importing the ec folder and setting it as the base folder I can get the ec. referencing to work. Now I have a problem with finding the tutorial java file.